# Programatically compare source and target of a branch in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am building a VS2008 plug-in to track the releases from developer. As a part of the requirement I need to find out which part of the source the developer modified by comparing the local source file against the source branch.

I like to know how to get the server item for a local source file and also the server item for its source branch.